# How to change the cache-line size of Non blocking data cache in Rocket Chip?

Tags: scala, chisel, rocket-chip

I am doing some experiments on NBDCache of Rocket Chip. I want to change cache-line size, and illustrate the trade-off between performance improvement and storage overhead of L1 Cache.

As I figured out the default value for the cache line in rocket chip is 64 bits, which is relatively small. I tried to change the cache line size by means of parameters defined for WithNBigCores in subsystem/config.scala but I got the following assertion while compiling the new code.

```
[error] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: rowBits(256) != cacheDataBits(64)
```

I am looking for the process of changing cache-line size in Rocket Chip.

```
class WithNBigCores(n: Int) extends Config((site, here, up) => {
  case RocketTilesKey => {
    val big = RocketTileParams(
      dcache = Some(DCacheParams(
        rowBits = 256 // site(SystemBusKey).beatBits,
        nMSHRs = 1,
        ...
    )))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of cache lines in Rocket-Chip is nearly hardwired to 64 Byte (rather than 64 bit) as you said. It is not an easy work to change it. The configurability on this part s not great I am afraid.

If you really, you need to revise the corresponding places in the NBDcache, including the data array, the part related to refill, anything related to the beat size of the TileLink.